# Slide DIV from left after load the website

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I need to create a jquery script to slide a DIV from

```
<left: -200px>
```

to

```
<left: 0px>
```

after the page loads. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("divID").css("margin-left", -$(this).width()).animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Oh ..I see ..  $10000  please.you have to give it by hand.

Comment: you should show some interest in solving your own problem

Comment: You can find cheaper developer than suresh but with suresh you know your money will be in good hand...

Comment: If you plan to start using jQuery it pays to spend a half hour or so browsing through the [list of methods](http://api.jquery.com/). (Where you'll quickly come across the `.animate()` method...)

Comment: Next time post it in your question...

Comment: i know ...i have gone through this... 1st question and -7 votes in just 10 sec...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`$.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties.

```
$('#divID').animate({
     left: '0'
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: zero is zero so 0 is enough ;)

Comment: @roasted.. yup.. i had just 0 there first.. anyways.. thanks.. :)

Comment: BTW: `left: 0` would avoid some cast  ;)